# Why can java -Xms exceed available memory when in docker container?

Tags: java, docker, memory, out-of-memory

I am running a java application within a docker container and java allows me to specify a -Xms size well in excess of the memory available to the container. Why is this the case?

When running outside of a container I get the expected result:

```
$ free -g; java -Xms100g -version
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             31          14          17           0           0          17
Swap:            28           0          28
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f5f60a00000, 71583137792, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 71583137792 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

But when I run the same command from within a docker container

```
$ free -g; java -Xms100g -version
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              4           0           3           0           0           3
Swap:             0           0           0
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

The command somehow succeeds. Checking the JVM parameters, it doesn't look like the container is overriding JVM parameters. It looks like java thinks it successfully allocated a heap size 25 time larger than the available memory:

```
 java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal  -Xms100g -version 2>&1 | grep InitialHeapSize
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 107374182400                        {product}
```

Why does this happen?

Both systems are Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (WSL vs `FROM ubuntu:18.04`) and java 1.8.0_222. Docker desktop 2.1.0.3 (38240). Win10 host OS.